# Infinite python generator

Tags: python, generator

I have been leaning python and programming for not so long. So you may find my question silly.
I am reviewing generator and try to generate 'yes', 'no' infinitely just to understand the concept.

I have tried this code but having "yes" each time

```
def yes_or_no():
    answer = ["yes","no"]
    i=0
    while True:
        if i >=2:
            i=0
        yield answer[i]
        i+=1

c=next(yes_or_no())

print(c)
print(c)
print(c)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 5):

`yes_no()` produces the generator; you want to call `next` on the same generator each time, rather than printing the same first element over and over.

```
c = yes_no()

print(next(c))
print(next(c))
# etc.
```

That said, there's no need for a separate counter; just yield `yes`, then yield `no`, then repeat.

```
def yes_or_no():
    while True:
        yield "yes"
        yield "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the generator and then call `next` on the initialized generator object:

```
c = yes_or_no()
```

Now you need to call `next` on `c`:

```
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
```

---

In your current code `c=next(yes_or_no())`:

- `yes_or_no()` will initialize the generator and calling `next` on it will get the first `yes` and you're saving that `yes` as name `c`
- In the next lines, you're just printing same `yes` referred by `c` while doing `print(c)`

Answer (score 1):

While your function does return a generator and it has been stated by others that all you need to do is iterate over it using a loop or calling next in succession. Python provides you a great library called `itertools` to do exactly this thing; it's called [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). This is all the code you need to replicate your functions ability:

```
def yes_no():
    return itertools.cycle(['yes', 'no'])
```

And just like others have said, a generator can be iterated over using `next` or a loop.

```
>>> c = yes_no()
>>> next(c) 
'yes'
>>> next(c) 
'no'
...
```

Comment: The function is not a generator; the return value of the function is.

Comment: Edited to state as so